# Error marker in Eclipse is not shown

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to have error-markers (see red rectangles in my screenshot) if the Java file contains compilation errors.

Does anybody know which settings must be turned on?

Unfortunately it is not possible to reinstall Eclipse because I cannot do this at work :-(

The following screenshot shows an error and no error markers in Eclipse:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Try `Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Annotations -> Errors`, or something like that.

Comment: Your eclipse installation seems to have severe problems - never saw those ugly black boxes in the project explorer before.

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ I had a look at that menu option but it doesn't seem to affect icons on the files.

Comment: But this is only for annotations in the editor and not in the navigation bar?

Comment: They only show there when the file is built while having errors.

Comment: Try cleaning the project (Project -> Clean...) and build it again (Project -> Build Project). Sometimes Eclipse gets confused, what markers to show and where. If that does not help, try creating a new workspace, as it might be a problem with the workspace settings. (Remind: Workspace preferences can be copied.)

Answer (score 0):

I had this kind of problem once 
I just went through the following steps.

1.Open the eclipse and wait until the project gets build.
2.Clean the project and server or (Build the project again as in my case I was using maven based project)
3.Run as->

Answer (score 0):

select `Proyect > Build Automatically`

or

clean your proyect in `Proyect > Clean > Select Your Proyect`

or

In Proyect Explorer select `Build Path > Build Path Configure` change to your Java SDK (via JRE System Library -> Alternate JRE).

In my case I had a Library (missing). I deleted it